# Graph is connected or not ! in c language for ford fulkersion

Tags: c, algorithm, graph, ford-fulkerson

// i created this as a part of ford fulkersion algorithm

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    int v,i,e,ch[20],sv[20],count=0,s,j;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter No of vertices :");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    for(i=1;i<=v;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter vertices %d",i);
        scanf("%d",&sv[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter starting node : ");
    scanf("%d",&s);
```

//Problem in this below loop(logic is not working ) if any one have solution please help !

```
    for(i=s;i<=v-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<=v;j++)
        {
            printf("conn betn %d and %d",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&ch[i]);
            if(ch[i]!=1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(ch[i]==1)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

//----------------------------------------------------------

```
if(count>=v)
{
    printf("Graph is connected");
}
else
{
    printf("Graph is disconnected");
}
getch();
```

}

Comment: 1. It is not clear what "not working" means. 2. It would be easier to answer it if you have added a description of the algorithm you are using, not just the code.

Comment: let me clear you i am checking the graph is connected or not and their is no algorithm this code is created by me on basis of my thinking ! if you have any other code to check the graph is connected or not then please give that link !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong. You are assuming that if you have at least v edges, your graph is connected. But if you have a graph like this, with 6 nodes and 6 edges, it is still not connected:

[image]